# Ho can i get data from sales_invoiced_aggregated table

Tags: magento-1.9, database, orders, invoice

I am trying to export invoice report data externally.

How can i collect data from this table `sales_invoiced_aggregated`?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can use the `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Invoiced_Collection_Invoiced` collection class directly as it's using the resource from the `sales_invoiced_aggregated` table:

```
class Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Invoiced_Collection_Invoiced
    extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Invoiced_Collection_Order
{
    /**
     * Initialize custom resource model
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setModel('adminhtml/report_item');
        $this->_resource = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/report')->init('sales/invoiced_aggregated');
        $this->setConnection($this->getResource()->getReadConnection());
    }
}
```

So you can do stuff like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/report_invoiced_collection');
```

NB you can also use a date range to filter your collection:

```
$collection->setDateRange($from, $to);
```

Comment: $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/report_invoiced_collection'); var_dump($collection);   says bool(false) , and not returning me anythings